# How to make String of different values from same $_GET PHP (different links)

Tags: php, get

Imagine i have this two links:

```
<a href=backoffice.php?numero=1>1</a>';  
<a href=backoffice.php?numero=2>2</a>';
```

Once i press link with $numero=1 i want this:

$code = $_GET['number']; output = '1'.

AFTER, i want to press link with $numero =2 and i want this:

$code= $code + $_GET['number']; output = '12'.

I can't find a possible way to get this without "restarting the code and always get the number i have in the $_GET at that moment".

I tried to save it in an array but every time I press link, the array restarts and i always have one number instead of two.

ANSWER: Use sessions and make a new session to restart the session, so if you want to restart the "$code" you must unset the session of stored numbers.

Comment: save your $_GET['numero'] into a session variable.

Comment: not sure that static thingy gonna work @MichaelLaffargue

Comment: btw maybe it could be done also as `<a href=backoffice.php?numero=1&current=<?=$_GET['numero'];?>>1</a>` then summing `$_GET['current'] + $_GET['numero'];`

Comment: @RoyalBg You're right it'll be static only for the request life length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a session when u first get the link clicked

```
<?php
session_start();
$output=NULL;
if(isset($_SESSION['stored'])){
    $_SESSION['stored'].=$_GET['number']; \\ this will keep on appending the number eq. 1212...
}else {
    $_SESSION['stored']=$_GET['number'];
}
$ouput=$_SESSION['stored']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As goldlife sad, start a session (before any output in the buffer), and concatenate the numbers.

```
<?php
session_start(); //Do it before any output in the buffer
?>


<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"]; ?>/?numero=1">1</a><br />
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"]; ?>/?numero=2">2</a><br />
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"]; ?>/?numero=3">3</a><br />
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELFT"]; ?>/?numero=4">4</a><br />

<?php
if (empty($_SESSION["numbers"])) {
    $_SESSION["numbers"] = '';
}
if (!empty($_GET["numero"])) {
    $_SESSION["numbers"] .= $_GET["numero"];
}
echo "The numbers is " . $_SESSION["numbers"];
```